# sql - aggregate count and share by group

Tags: postgresql

with table `t1` like below, need to get the count by each `make` and the share by each make

```
+--------+
| make   |
+--------+
| toyota |
| audi   |
| bmw    |
| bmw    |
| audi   |
+--------+
```

with below I can get get the car_cnt per make

```
select
 make
 , count (*) as car_cnt
from t1
group by make
```

how do I get the share (%) for each `make` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `COUNT` as an analytic function, we can make a single pass over your table and compute the market share for each car.

```
select distinct
    make,
    count(*) over (partition by make) as car_cnt,
    100.0 * count(*) over (partition by make) / count(*) over () as car_pct
from t1
```

**Output:**

```
    make    car_cnt car_pct
1   audi    2       40
2   bmw     2       40
3   toyota  1       20
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester